# Parameterize import resource in spring bean file

Tags: java, spring, datasource, propertyconfigurator

I have a datasource.xml as following. I have two sql bean files for mySql and Oracle as some queries are dependent on the database, as for limit in mysql equivalent to rownum in oracle.I import the resource files from either oracle folder or mysql folder. For now, I have to go and change import statement before build. Is there any alternative like to have the database name in a property file.PropertyConfigurer does not work with import statement at least for Spring 3.0.5.

```
<import resource="classpath:oracle/SqlBeans.xml" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" >
        <value>${ds-jndi}</value>
    </property> 
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>

 <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
```

Comment: Take a look at Spring Profiles (for example http://blog.chariotsolutions.com/2012/01/spring-31-cool-new-features.html) but it's Spring 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Spring profiles, mentioned by @RC, is a good idea but requires 3.1 I think.

This might be simpler:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db-${my.env}.properties"/>
```

And set `my.env` on the java command line.

See [this](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2009/04/20/6-tips-for-managing-property-files-with-spring/).